# Why does import urllib fail if import matplotlib is absent?

Tags: python, import, urllib

I'm running python 3.4 under Win7.

Why does 'import urllib' fail if 'import matplotlib' is absent?

```
import urllib
import socket
import sys, os
import matplotlib.pyplot # urllib won't work unless this is here ! WTF?? !

url='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY/history?period1=1410652800&period2=1536883200&interval=1d'
bytes = urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=4).read()
page = str( bytes, encoding='utf8' ) 
print("Page length="+str(len(page)))
sys.exit
```

Without import matplotlib.pyplot, program fails with this error:

```
File "C:\Python34\minibigdrops.py", line 8, in module
bytes = urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=4).read()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'
```

The other attributes, like 'error', aren't found either.

I see that several others have posted problems with urllib. Perhaps they could try also importing matplotlib.

Comment: Have you tried `import urllib.request` instead of `import urllib` ?

Comment: (side note: I'd not name your result `bytes` - that's a builtin name (albeit it very unlikely to want to be used as such))

Comment: jon: Yes, and I got the same result. Ditto with urllib.error. I also moved the entire urllib files into my program, and it still said it couldn't find them. And the variable really isn't named bytes - I changed it for this note for clarity.